# Usar befereSend em ajax para fazer uma tela de carregamento em Modal

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax

Estou tentando fazer uma tela de carregando usando modal e jquery, em que enquanto está coletando as informações do banco de dados, tem que aparecer carregando. Porém mesmo depois de já ter carregado, não está sumindo o modal. Segue o código:

```
<!-- Modal aguarde -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalaguarde" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAguarde" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-aguarde modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                   <img src="img/carregando.gif" class="modal-img"> 
                   <h5>carregando...</h5>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div><!-- Fim Modal -->


$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.play').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'url...',
            type: 'post',
            data:  {},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#modalaguarde').modal('show');
            },success: function(data){
                $('#modalaguarde').modal('hide');
            }
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: A div principal não está fechada com `</div>`.

Comment: Removi a resposta temporariamente. Eu havia dito: "Ah sim, então a história muda rss... faz um teste, comenta tudo dentro do success e deixa só o código que fecha a modal para ver se funciona."

Answer (score 0):

Esse comportamento pode ser apresentado, quando você manda esconder uma modal em um momento em que ela não terminou de abrir ela pode estar em um estado que vai ignorar o argumento de `hide`. E no seu caso está relacionado ao `fade` em `<div class="modal fade">`.

Uma opção de contorno é utilizar um `setTimeout()` para retardar a instrução de `hide`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.play').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();        
     
$.ajax({
          url: '#',
          type: 'post',
          data: {},
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          beforeSend: function() {            
            $('#modalaguarde').modal('show')
          },
          success: function(data) {
            //seu codigo
          },
          error: function(data){
            //tratamento do erro
          },
         complete: function() {
           
            setTimeout(function()
            {            
              $('#modalaguarde').modal('hide');
            }, 2000);
          }
        
      });

      
  });
});
```

```css
@import 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal aguarde -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalaguarde" role="dialog" abindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalAguarde" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-aguarde modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="text-center">
          <img src="img/carregando.gif" class="modal-img">
          <h5>carregando...</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="play">play</button>
<!-- Fim Modal -->
```